# call nodejs file onclick function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, node.js

Basicaly i have a function called `Register()` in my javascript `script.js`.

Inside this function, i should call a nodejs file called `sms.js`.

`sms.js` is a CORS enabled, which calls an API and then it return some `JSON`

I want to get this JSON response inside my `Register()` function of my javascript

What is the ideal way to achieve this? Usually when i run `node sms.js` this API is called and i am getting the required `JSON` response

Inside my `Register` function i have

```
$.get('/#/request', function(list) {
    console.log(list);
});
```

Inside my `sms.js` function i have

```
app.get('/#/request', function(req, res){
});
```

So this doesnt work at all.. because `node sms.js` have to run.. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `require('./sms.js')` inside the main nodeJS file that has the server listeners. Because what you are doing is asynchronous you should return a promise and wait for it to be fulfilled. Inside the sms.js file you need to use `module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){//do whatever you want here and then call resolve(yourdata);}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple example will help you

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/